# Get name of subclass of ndb.StructuredProperty(subclass, repeated=True)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Given a [NDB Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) (Google AppEngine) model definition:

```
class Customer(ndb.Model):
    products = ndb.StructuredProperty(Product, repeated=True)
```

The model Customer defines a repeated sub-model, called Product. How can I get the name of the sub-model, in this case "Product"?

Comment: `getattr(Customer, 'products')` returns `StructuredProperty(Product, 'products', repeated=True)`. maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

`getattr(Customer, 'products')._modelclass`

Although if you use any method/properties prefixed with a `_` you will be responsible for underlying API changes to the ndb library.

Comment: Thanks! I used `getattr(Customer, 'products')._modelclass.__name__`to get the actual name. I googled for "._modelclass" but was not able to find any documentation about it. Can you help me out?

Comment: I checked out the source code: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#2095. Also, you could compare using `getattr(Customer, 'products')._modelclass == Products` instead of relying on the name, unless you have a different use case.

Comment: The _ properties in NDB are supposed to be part of it's API, according to the creator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690418/how-to-programmatically-determine-if-ndb-property-is-multivalue ... many months later, still not documented though! (Direct link to issue to star: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=187 )

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I remember reading somewhere while NDB was still experimental that the use of `_` prefixed properties were meant to be used for internal purposes only.