# Find if attribute of a model is 'required'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, models, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to write a restful service of my own for google app engine. I am dynamically fetching form data and saving the model. To get the attribute list , I am doing

```
Contact.__properties
{'name': StringProperty('name', required=True), 'email': StringProperty('email', required=True)}
```

I can do this to find the type of the attribute

```
(Pdb) type(Contact._properties['name']) is ndb.StringProperty
True
```

But how can I find if it is required = True or False

What is the type of the output of Contact._properties, how do I decipher it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [poorly documented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10704614/100297), there *is* an introspection API for NDB models; simply use the name of the configuration option with an underscore prefixed:

```
Contact._properties['name']._required
```

is the value of the `required` option.

The underscores do not signify 'privacy' here but are used to avoid clashing with names from the model itself (e.g. if `name` were a `StructuredProperty` referencing another model with a `required` property you wouldn't otherwise be able to access the `required` *option*).

Comment: woah !! seriously, that simple ? 
Thanks , I believe other such properties can be accessed similarly.

Comment: Yep it really is that simple.  Use dir() with objects and that will show you a lot.  as in dir(Contact._properties['name']) at the pdb shell

Comment: @Skeptor: yes; all properties are supposed to be exposed like that.